# Is there any plugin to ignore capital letter starts with widgets in flutter?(android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

everytime when i want to write a widget in flutter by android studio i have to press my capslock to be on capital letter so that the auto complete work for me and it's very annoying .
Is there any way to get through it ?

Comment: Why would you hit caps lock. Try to use shift key in combination with the letter to type in caps.

Comment: oh thank you i didn't know that

Comment: please make your cmment as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to hit caps lock everytime..you can just use shift + anyAlphabet